# How to save user input data and display it with Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to make a basic app with 3 pages where the user can submit contact data(name, number, and email)on a SecondActivity page and on the MainActivity page, the name will be displayed as a list with other submitted names and the user can click on the name and it will navigate to a ThirdActivity page and display the number and email of the selected contact name. So far, I've made a form on the SecondActivity page for the user to input data. However it is not being saved and it is not being displayed. I'm very new to android studio and I'm hoping someone can give me direction on what to do next or good sources to read over. I will post my codes.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    int request_Code = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void onClick(View view) {

        startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.example.usingintent.SecondActivity"),request_Code);
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == request_Code) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this,data.getData().toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent data = new Intent();
//---get the EditText view---
        EditText txt_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
//---set the data to pass back---
        data.setData(Uri.parse( txt_username.getText().toString()));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

//        phone below
        EditText txt_phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
//---set the data to pass back---
        data.setData(Uri.parse( txt_phone.getText().toString()));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

//        email below
        EditText txt_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
//---set the data to pass back---
        data.setData(Uri.parse( txt_email.getText().toString()));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);



//---closes the activity---
        finish();
    }

}
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.usingintent.SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the Second Activity!"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<!--    textview for name below-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please enter your name"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername" />

<!--    texview for phoner number below-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please enter your phone number"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone" />
<!--    textview for email below-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please enter your e-mail"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Main Activity!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Display second activity"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use Local database using Room. Link for reference https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) You can use intend. An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with StartActivity like this:

Sending data between activities:

```
Intent intentLocal = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intentLocal.putExtra("fieldName",fieldValue);
 startActivity(intentLocal);
    finish();
```

Receive data from activity:(in onCreate method)

```
String getFieldValue = getIntent().getString("fieldName");
```